# How to get data from Intent in the Fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am confused about how to use intent.getStringExtra in Fragments. "val uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid")" This code works fine in the categories but now working in the fragment. Does someone have the solution?

I am trying to get data from the Firestore.
So here is the thing we have categories in categories we have Nature, Art & more. So to get the name of the Categorie we used the "UID" to get the id of that particular category. Hope it's clear now. The UID has no value idk I am planning to get the category name in it. Like in the text view.

[Here's the database I've to get the name of the category in the text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y36n7.png)

Categorie Fragment code!!!

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid") //Stuck Here
       db.collection("categories").document(uid!!).collection("categoriewallpaper")
           .addSnapshotListener { value, _ ->
               val listOfCatData = arrayListOf<CatModel>()
               val data = value?.toObjects(CatModel::class.java)
               listOfCatData.addAll(data!!)
```

Comment: Which scope did you put these code in? like in `onCreate`?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how you add the "uid" to the intent. Besides that, if you try to log the value of `intent.getStringExtra("uid")`, are getting something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @flutroid Yes in the onCreateView

Comment: @AlexMamo I am trying to get the data from the firestore into the text view. I hope this helped you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: What is the value of `uid` inside `.document(uid!!)`? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've updated it please check & let me know.

Comment: What is the value of `uid` inside `.document(uid!!)`?

Comment: I Don't Know, I was trying to get the category's name so I wrote that.  There is no value in it, ignore it & I hope you get what I am trying to attain so please help me with the code. @AlexMamo

Comment: Without it, I cannot be much of a help.

Comment: Hey the value of the UID is the ID mentioned in the category wallpaper. Open the Firestore image on the bottom left we have the id the name & the link. So id the is the value of UID.

Comment: @AlexMamo please look into this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more context.